# Polygon pour for power MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, pcb, dc-dc-converter, heat

This is a part of the PCB I'm designing for a DC-DC converter, this is a switching node of one channel with 4A current rating. I used paralleled MOSFETs to decrease the thermal stress. Per my calculations, there would be around 0.8W power loss per MOSFET.

How should I calculate the polygon pour surface needed for this power loss?

I'd also appreciate any feedback or suggestions to enhance the heat dissipation for the MOSFETs.

[image]

Comment: Datasheets give thermal resistance info for both recommended footprint without any copper pour, and a copper pour for reference (e.g. 4 cm²). 'suggestions to enhance the heat dissipation' Put another copper pour on bottom layer while keeping the isolation requirements, if any, in mind. And connect top and bottom copper with vias, preferably around the drain pads.

Comment: What is ambient temperature? Maximum allowed (PCB or device or etc.) temperature? What were your calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Connecting that top pour to the sources of the lower FETs makes little sense, because the heat internally arises in the drain region. So the lower FETs want their own pour on their drains. This also helps keep the switch node small.

Which links to another point: For switching converters, you want the switch node to be small because it radiates a lot of E field. So these converters might not be ideal to dump all heat into a large drain pour. Don't expand it too much. Instead make a few cm² L1 pour and use tight coupling (thin dielectric) to an extended ground plane on L2 for the heat dispersion. If not enough, a grounded heat sink can be attached on the components themselves.

If the drain node doesn't give off a lot of E fields (linear regulators for example), then the drain pour can be larger and can be extended to other layers using plenty of vias.